# C++: Using %n with strftime

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, wxwidgets, strftime

I am developing an application in `C++` using `VS2010`.  I tried using the format `"%d-%m-%y %n %H:%M:%S"` with `strfime` and I got runtime error telling `Debug assert Failed: “Invalid format directive”`. On trying to solve the problem, I found that `%n` is part of `C++11` and is not supported by `VS2010`. So my question is : Is there some other way by which I can have the date and time in two different lines? I have no option to use other versions of VS.

EDIT:

Actually I am using the library `wxfreechart` to create a graph. Date and time appears in the X-axis. In `wxfreechart` I have the function `SetDateFormat()` which accepts `date format in strftime style` (http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/docs/freechart/classDateAxis.html). My code is actually as follows :

```
bottomAxis->SetDateFormat(wxT("%d-%m-%y %n %H:%M:%S"));
```

`\n` instead of `%n` gives nothing here.

Sorry for my mistake regarding `strftime`.

Comment: Are you sure that new line is supported by `wxfreechart`? Perhaps, any spaces (including `\n` and `\t` are replaced with ` ` (single space). I mean, that usage of strftime style is not necessarily call `strftime`, and not even necessarily support C++ standard

Comment: @VolAnd: I dnt get any error while using \t and \n in wxfreechart. But it doesnot provide newline or tab space as well.

Comment: So, problem is not in the `strftime`, that is feature of `DateAxis` and `SetDateFormat`

Comment: @VolAnd: So I dont have an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, try printing the formatted string `"%d-%m-%y \n %H:%M:%S"`, thus replace `"%n"` by `"\n"`. In that way it should be working in the older C++ standard, thus in VS2010.

Otherwise you could perhaps you could consider upgrading to a newer version of visual studio.

Here is a good reference :http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

Comment: i have tried it..but doesn't work..And I am not supposed to use other versions

Comment: Upgrading VS versions, any compiler version really, can be fraught with political nightmare in the world of professional programming. I've been trying to ditch GCC 3.3 for years, but we have this old project that formed the model used for subsequent build systems and still is being actively developed and supported and you don't willy-nilly change a system that works without an extensive roadmap.

Comment: @Jackzz "i have tried it..but doesn't work" - What have you tried?

Comment: @VolAnd: I tried `"%d-%m-%y \n %H:%M:%S"` and I just got a space between date and time

Comment: @Jackzz So, I understand correctly, and checked... and it works at my PC with VS2010 (see my example in answer below, until I delete it). Perhaps, you should rebuild project and check `\n` again

Comment: @VolAnd: Sorry..So it works with strftime!! I will edit my question so as to meet my requirment

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with `strftime`, but with my usage of `wxfreechart`. I had to set `verticallabeltext` to `false` and then I could use `\n` as in `strftime`.

```
bottomAxis->SetVerticalLabelText(false);
bottomAxis->SetDateFormat(wxT("%d-%m-%y\n%H:%M:%S"));
```